# shuffled index without need of memory

Tags: algorithm, shuffle

I need a function with profile

```
int shuffledIndex(seed, index, range)
```

for every index in the range returns a random other index from the range, but for a single seed all the values will be returned once and only once.

There are tons of algorithms that for a given container they can apply shuffling procedure, but I am not looking for such.

I need something that will not require extra memory, because the range is relatively big and will have many simultaneous seed sessions at the same time.

The shuffling does not need to be extremely strong and there could be limitation about the range - say being with size that is power of 2.

Are you aware of such algorithm?

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't shuffle particularly well, but multiplying by an odd number modulo a power of two gives a bijection, so if you input all the indexes you get a permutation of them. You could also add an offset to prevent 0 from mapping to itself for every seed.

For example, in C# or similar: (requires `range` to be a power of two)

```
int shuffledIndex(int seed, int index, int range)
{
    return (index * (seed | 1) + seed) & (range - 1);
}
```

Comment: this will generate lines, that just rotate from time to time, right? The shuffle does not need to be great, but this does not seem enough.

Comment: @gsf how well does it have to be shuffled then? (have you tried this btw?)